# PrintF and Scanf result is zero

Tags: beginner, c

I am a beginner working on a code project. I'm simply trying to make my program multiply a user's input by a constant, however when I run the program I only get 0 as a result.

sorry this is a basic question, I just can't find a solution anywhere else.

int main() {

```
double quanity, result;
const double USD = 0.81;

result = USD * quanity;

printf("Please input a number.\n");
scanf("%f", &quanity);
printf("%f\n", result);

return 0;
```

}

Comment: This is off topic for code review - code review is for asking for feedback on already-working code. (The problem here is your order, you assign result before you ask for input on quantity, try moving that line below the scanf)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You are trying to multiply USD Variable with undefined variable "quanity",
you should make the assignment operation after you get the "quanity" from user.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

double quanity, result;
const double USD = 0.81;

//Scan the number first
printf("Please input a number.\n");
scanf("%f", &quanity);

//then make the assignment operation
result = USD * quanity;

printf("%f\n", result);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please, don't answer questions that are off-topic here.

Comment: (Most of the code you present needs more indentation, by the way.)

Comment: `printf("%f\n", result);` prints with a default 6 digits after the `.'`.  Rarely is this wanted with money.

Comment: Using `argv[1]` without first validating `argc >= 2` is not defensive coding.